# Find parameter ranges of a function whose value is within a window by sampling points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation, parametric-functions, iteration

## Problem:

I want to find the ranges of the parameters for a function $f(x,y,z)$ when $0.9 < f(x,y,z) < 1.1$. All parameters are bounded $x , y, z \in [0,1]$. In the real problem the function takes more than 3 parameters, and it is hard to visualize.

So I am trying to narrow down the range by numerical evaluation of the sampling points, e.g.

```
Table[ f[x,y,z], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}, {z, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

But that only gives me a table of function values, not the choices of `x`, `y`, `z`.

My preferred output format would be a table with element,

> x, y, z, f(x, y, z)

where the 4th column is within the range $[0.9,1.1]$

## Questions:

- How to generate that output?

I am inexperienced in Mathematica programming. I reckoned that I can generate a nested table of parameters, and a nested table of function values. And then iterate through the table to filter out those with value $\in[0.9,1.1]$. But I do not know how to implement that in Mathematica.

- Is this the best way to find the range?

The purpose of the program is to find the pattern for further analytical study.
One can assume that the function is bounded and smooth almost everywhere.

It could also be interpreted as an optimization problem. But that may be too intensive. At this stage I just want to just have a quick look. If only $x,y$ are the parameters, I could have just used `ParametericPlot3D`.

Thanks!

## Update

@bill gives a solution:

```
Select[Flatten[Table[{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]},{x,0,1,.1},{y,0,1,.1},{z,0,1,.1}],2],.9<Last[#]<1.1&]
```

I want to ask a follow up question. Suppose I want to focus on the choices of `x` and `y` coordinate, how can I remove the duplicated entries in this table, which have the same `x` and `y` (but different `z`)?

I searched that one can use `DeleteDuplicates`, but this removes elements whose `x`, `y`, `z` and `f[x,y,z]` are the same.

## Solution for the follow-up:

We can still use `DeleteDuplicates`

```
DeleteDuplicates[data, Take[#1, 2] == Take[#2, 2] &]
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205096/how-to-delete-duplicate-based-on-a-portion-of-list-item-only-in-mathematica), or @Bill's comments below.

Comment: @Bill, it works when you change `Flatten` to the 2nd level: `Select[Flatten[Table[{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]},{x,0,1,.1},{y,0,1,.1},{z,0,1,.1}],2],.9<Last[#]<1.1&]`. Then `Flatten` gives a nested table, whose element is `{x,y,z,f(x,y,z)}`. `Select` with criterion `0.9 < Last[#] < 1.1 &` filers out the  output. Thanks.

Comment: If all that `#` and `&` stuff is difficult for you at this stage then here is a different way of doing the same thing `yourlist={{1,1,2,3},{1,1,3,4},{2,1,3,3},{2,2,3,3},{3,3,4,5}};
areXsandYsequal[{x1_,y1_,z1_,v1_},{x2_,y2_,z2_,v2_}]:=x1==x2&&y1==y2;
DeleteDuplicates[yourlist,areXsandYsequal]` and you should see it eliminates any duplicates that share the same xs and ys. I suggest you display your list and the result of deleting the duplicates and check them off one by one to verify this. Then you can try the `#` and `&` version and see if it gives the same results. Please check for errors.

Comment: @Bill, thank you. I can understand the method for `DeleteDuplicates`. You can provide a test function there, the `Take` function takes out the first two elements. I guess `&` means an anonymous function?